# Timestamp of socket in /proc/<pid>/fd

Tags: linux, proc, file-descriptors

If I list `/proc/<pid>/fd` I see a number of entries for sockets.  These entries have timestamps.  At first I thought they were when the socket was created.  But it doesn't always appear to be the case.

What does this timestamp mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the entries in `/proc/x/fd` are *instantiated* the first time you access them (via a `lstat(2)` or any system call that has them involved), and that's where the time comes from.

Comment: Do you know where I can see the kernel source for this?

Comment: Somewhere in `fs/proc/`, probably `fs/proc/base.c`