# When was a process started

Tags: linux, process, ps, proc

To know when was a process started, my first guess was to check the time when `/proc/<pid>/cmdline` was written/modified the last time.

`ps` also shows a `START` field. I thought both of these sources would be the same. Sometimes they are not the same. How could that be?

Comment: [Already asked on Serverfault in 2009](https://serverfault.com/questions/95643/linux-how-do-i-see-when-a-process-started).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

On Linux at least, you can also do:

```
ps -o lstart= -p the-pid
```

to have a more useful start time.

Note however that it's the time the *process* was started, not necessarily the time the *command* that it is currently executing was invoked. Processes can (and generally do) run more than one command in their lifetime. And commands sometimes spawn other processes.

The mtimes of the files in `/proc` on Linux (at least) are generally the date when those files were instantiated, which would be the first time something tried to access them or list the directory content.

For instance:

```
$ sh -c 'date +%T.%N; sleep 3; echo /proc/"$$"/xx*; sleep 3; stat -c %y "/proc/$$/cmdline"'
13:39:14.791809617
/proc/31407/xx*
2013-01-22 13:39:17.790278538 +0000
```

Expanding `/proc/$$/xx*` caused the shell to read the content of `/proc/$$` which caused the `cmdline` file to be instantiated.

See also: [Timestamp of socket in /proc//fd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55924)

Answer (score 18):

*proc* is a virtual file system so I wouldn't rely on any file status information.

The start time of the process is located at */proc/PID/stat* column *22*. It is given in jiffies after system boot. To convert it to seconds you have to divide it by `sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)` which is 100 for *most* systems (but not all!).

To get the time of system boot you determine the current uptime in seconds which is the first value of */proc/uptime*.

Having those two numbers you subtract the first from the second and you get the number of seconds passed since starting the program.

Example (for *pidgin*):

```
PID=$(pidof pidgin)
STARTTIME=$(awk '{print int($22 / 100)}' /proc/$PID/stat)
UPTIME=$(awk '{print int($1)}' /proc/uptime)
NOW=$(date +%s)
DIFF=$((NOW - (UPTIME - STARTTIME)))
date -d @$DIFF
```

Note: this simple example doesn't work if `pidof` returns multipe PIDs.

Comment: Any idea about when does proc/<pid>/cmdline gets written to? well any of proc/<pid> entries for that matter.

Comment: Usually those files are generated by the kernel *dynamically* whenever you try to read them and most of them also have a dynamical content. *cmdline* doesn't but I can't imagine that there is an official policy stating that is has to be created once on process startup and never be touched again.

Comment: You can get _SC_CLK_TCK value from command line by executing "getconf CLK_TCK"