# Get process age from command line

Tags: linux, shell-script, process-management

In linux, from `/proc/PID/stat`, I can get the `start_time` (22:nd) field, which indicates how long after the kernel booted the process was started.

What is a good way to convert that to a seconds-since-the-epoch format? Adding it to the `btime` of `/proc/stat`?

Basically, I'm looking for the **age** of the process, not exactly when it was started. My first approach would be to compare the `start_time` of the process being investigated with the `start_time` of the current process (assuming it has not been running for long).

Surely there must be way better ways.

I didn't find any obvious age-related parameters when looking at https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt

So, What I have currently is:

```
process age = (current_utime - ([kernel]btime + [process]start_time))
```

Any alternative ways that are more efficient from within a shell script? (Ideally correct across DST changes)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since version 3.3.0, the `ps` of `procps-ng` on Linux has a `etimes` output field that gives you the elapsed time in seconds since the process was started (which by the way is not necessarily the same thing as the elapsed time since the last time that process executed a command (if at all!) (the time that process has been running the command in the process name), so may not be as useful as you thought).

So you can do:

```
ps -o etimes= -p "$pid"
```

For the start time as Unix epoch time (with GNU `date`):

```
(export TZ=UTC0 LC_ALL=C; date -d "$(ps -o lstart= -p "$pid")" +%s)
```

Note that you cannot use the modification time of `/proc/$pid`. [That is just the time those files were instantiated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/62162) which has nothing to do with the start time of the process.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 11):

age of process : human readable form

```
ps -p 1234 -o etime -h
        1-02:03:04
```

second since epoch for a process

```
stat --format=%Y /proc/1234
```

Age in second

```
expr $(date +%s) - $(stat --format=%Y /proc/1234)
```

additionnal ressources `ps(1)`, `stat(1)`

Comment: The first and third do not appear to address the question.

Comment: question is unclear, OP ask both for  second-since-epoch and age. (second-since-started)

Comment: I got three different results: the first failed, the second worked (1445849311), and the third gave me 16 (apparently *not* seconds since the epoch).

Comment: second is start time since epoch, third is age in second

Comment: using stat on the process' /proc/PID directory was clever! Didn't think of that one myself. Feels a bit hackish, though.

Comment: @ThomasDickey the third addresses the question just fine IMHO: the process age (in seconds). The first one (-h) fails for me as well, and the output is very hard to parse.

Comment: That answer is incorrect at least on Linux [the mtime of /proc/1234 is not the start time of the process](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/62162)